# How to make booting alternative kernels options shown in top-level GRUB menu?

Tags: grub, gentoo

I use Gentoo Linux as my sole OS, so I would like to show the Gentoo boot options hiding in the "Advanced Options for Gentoo Linux" entry in my top-level (i.e., the one GRUB starts at, a lower-level menu would be the menu shown when I select and press enter on the "Advanced Options for Gentoo Linux" option) GRUB menu, is this possible? I know I could manually edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to get this done, but I would like a more permanent solution so I don't have to keep editing my `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file manually whenever `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` is re-run. As I would like to be able to choose an alternate kernel as soon as GRUB starts, without having to find the option within the "Advanced Options for Gentoo Linux" menu. To be clear I am using GRUB2 not GRUB Legacy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not used to Gentoo (only Ubuntu). But there in `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` the configuration is done, using variables defined in `/etc/default/grub` (paths may differ in Gentoo). See `man grub-mkconfig` or  `info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'`. The latter says:

```
The file '/etc/default/grub' controls the operation of
'grub-mkconfig'.  It is sourced by a shell script, and so must be valid
POSIX shell input; normally, it will just be a sequence of 'KEY=value'
lines...

'GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU'
     Normally, 'grub-mkconfig' will generate top level menu entry for
     the kernel with highest version number and put all other found
     kernels or alternative menu entries for recovery mode in submenu.
     For entries returned by 'os-prober' first entry will be put on top
     level and all others in submenu.  If this option is set to 'y',
     flat menu with all entries on top level will be generated instead.
     Changing this option will require changing existing values of
     'GRUB_DEFAULT', 'fallback' (*note fallback::) and 'default' (*note
     default::) environment variables as well as saved default entry
     using 'grub-set-default' and value used with 'grub-reboot'.
```

So, look for `/etc/default/grub` (or whereever it is) and set`GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=y`. Then rerun `grub-mkconfig`.

Comment: Surprised it was this easy, but thanks.

Comment: That's linux - most things are easy, when you know how to do.